# jquery position loading jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a problem with a jQuery position in local my code work good but when I put my script in the server it don't work in the first time, but when I refresh the page it work; "it can't load in the first opening my page"

My Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Atletprint</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"   >



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style type="text/css">



#container 
{

    position:absolute;


    bottom: 23%;
}

        body 
        { 
        background: url(Home.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
        }

.div
{
    display: inline-block;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>


<div   id="container">
    <a href="etiquette/index.html">
        <div  class="div">
            <img src="obj1.png"  >
        </div>
    </a>

    <a href="impression/index.html" class="div">
        <div  style="margin-left: 125px;">
            <img src="obj2.png">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

function test()
{
    location.reload();
}

$(document).ready(function() 
{
    function setMargins() 
{
    width = $(window).width();
    containerWidth = $("#container").width();  
    leftMargin = (width-containerWidth)/2;    
    $("#container").css("marginLeft", leftMargin);    
}




    setMargins();
    $(window).resize(function() 
    {
        setMargins();    
    });



});

</script>

<?php

header("location:index.php");


?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you explain why I see a header("location:index.php"); ? I'll tell you in advance: that line has to go, what ever else is required to solve your question.

Comment: If you are in chrome, try debugging with F12, if not put an alert just after $(document).ready(function() { to see what happens on your first load, this way you will see if it is a jquery issue or a code behind issue.